# A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to use file `index.d.ts`
content is :

```
declare const Icons= {
  "linkedin": "test",
  "twitter": "test2"
};
export default Icons;
export type Keys = keyof typeof Icons;
```

And I face this error
`A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference`
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you even have `declare const` *with a value*? What is the purpose?

Comment: You are not allowed to use values in `d.ts`. THese are only for types.  See [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRR47w)

Comment: I want to use this dependency [@rocket.chat/icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rocket.chat/icons) and this issue exist there, and i would like to fix it.

Comment: The fact is: you are not allowed to use values in `d.ts`